# Efficient way to merge elements of Collection in Java

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to implement a merge function which merge elements inside a List. To make it more

clear, I have `List<Set<String>>` which has list with data [{1,2,4},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{1,10}]

and I want result to be [{1,2,3,4,10},{5,6},{7,8}]

What is the most efficient way to do perform such a merge function?

Comment: I don't understand your merge function.

Comment: @MRalwasser: He wants to merge all sets that share elements in common.

Comment: Giving one example does not specify a function, or rather it specifies a function that has exactly one set of inputs.  I could come up with multiple functions that would pass your test case but fail for others.  Please use your words to describe what you actually want it to do.

Comment: You're looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: @SLaks: That's the likely interpretation, but you can't know for sure.  Maybe he wants a function which merges the first, second and last sets but leaves anything else in the middle.

Comment: @SLaks This was also my guess, but according to the example it's at least ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new list that will hold all the data.
2. Iterate through the list of sets.
3. Iterate through each set, adding each element in a set to the new list.
4. Done

This is kinda the manual way of doing it. The List class probably has some sort of addAll function.